# Activate maven profile when property is false or unset

Tags: maven

I'd like to activate a profile in my pom when tests aren't skipped.
Then and only then should my module depend on the test-jar of another module.
I'd like to detect if `maven.test.skip` is `false` or unset.
Unfortunately `<activation>` allows only one `<property>` child.

```
<profile>
    <id>add-test-depdendencies</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>maven.test.skip</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <!-- this fails because activation allows for only one property child node -->
        <property>
            <name>!maven.test.skip</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

My current workaround is to set `maven.test.skip` to `false` in settings.xml.

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

It works, but feels "unclean".
Is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need this profile? Why not put the test JAR on the classpath always?

Comment: If I allways put the test-jar in the classpath then it must be in my local repository or I need to download it when I add the `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` command line parameter. Because then that jar doesn't get packaged. I'm trying to speed up a slow multi-module build. Maybe this is futile.

Comment: Maybe there are other parts that would help more in speeding up. Like parallel building.

Comment: Why is that jar not packages? Is it contained in your own multi module build? Also using `mvn -T 5 clean package` to build faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with:

```
<activation>
        <property>
            <name>maven.test.skip</name>
            <value>!true</value>
        </property>
<activation>
```

The profile will be activated when the property `maven.test.skip` is not defined, or is defined with a value which is not `true`.